# Identifying treatment selection and outcomes with logistic regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, multivariate-analysis

We have 300 patients who underwent either surgery or a non-surgical treatment. We listed serious complications, regardless of what treatment they received. Other descriptive measures include age, sex, weight, smoking status, etc.

We want to answer the question: "Does surgery increase the risk of having a serious complication?"

We also want to answer the question: "What variable(s) predict surgical treatment vs non-surgical?"

For the first question, we plan to run a multiple logistic regression with any serious complication as the outcome and treatment choice as the main effect.

For the second question, we plan to run a multiple logistic regression, with treatment choice as dependent and the descriptive variables (age, sex, etc.) as independent variables.

This should tell us whether patients who smoke (for example) have a higher chance of being assigned a non-surgical method of treatment, correcting for age, weight, etc.

Does our method sound correct or are there any glaring holes in our approach?

Comment: A multivariate model is one in which there is more than one dependent (repsonse) variable.  Please edit your post accordingly.  I think you mean to discuss unadjusted estimates vs. multivariable-adjusted estimates.

Comment: Am I confusing multiple and multivariate regression? Should we use one outcome variable (surgery/conservative) and run a logistic multiple regression instead to answer the first question?

Comment: I have edited the question, I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Just to labour the point do you want to simultaneously model all complications as a vector, or do you want to model a composite variable of at least one complication possibly more?

Comment: The variable is simply Complication yes/no (0,1). Any patient who has had at least one serious complication regardless of procedure is included in this variable.

Comment: You say "subjects" were "assigned" treatment. Is it a randomized design or were patients allowed to choose what treatment they would take? The rest of the question suggests nobody was assigned anything, so it's an observational study with confounding.

Comment: It's a retrospective study using patient data. I realize my choice of words is confusing.